# Record - trigger flow: update a field after one day of the record's creation but not possible to do with a scheduled path

Tags: visual-workflow, field-update, recordtriggeredflow, updaterecord

I have to build a flow that runs when a record is created or updated. The context is the following:

- When the user creates a record in this custom object they have to choose a value from a picklist we have (My_Request_Is_Related_To__c --> it has 9 different values).
- That is the first decision in my flow. Depending on that value chosen I have to assign a user to that record. So far, I could do that.
- The thing is that if after 24hs the status is not "closed", I have to change the user again and tick a checkbox.

My question is the following, how can I update that field again with the second user after 24hs?

I have read some people who did it with a scheduled path but I cannot use that because I need to have my initial decision so I cannot schedule a path from the beginning.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  This is definitely doable with a record-triggered flow w/ scheduled paths. If this all depends on whether decision 1 is taken, then preserve that decision as state in a custom field of the object; then have a separate record-triggered flow w/ scheduled path deal with the +24 hr use case

Comment: @cropredy this doesn't just depend on the initial decision. The update that needs to happen after 24hs is the one I've just added and highlighted. I'm not seeing how I can make this work with a scheduled path, can you help me see it?

Comment: You need a second flow whose entry conditions are met when the record is DML'd. This flow is defined with a scheduled path +1 day from some reference date on the object.